# Extract value of single element from XML file in XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have below xml file and i want to extract a single element from any node,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <SubRoot>
        <type>A</type>
        <mand>Y</mand>
        <Section>B</Section>
    </SubRoot>
    <SubRoot>
        <type>B</type>
        <mand>Y</mand>
        <Section>A</Section>
    </SubRoot>
</root>
```

From the above xml file how can i get the value of `type` element from any `SubRoot` node in XSL.And number of  `SubRoot` node is unknown.it can be  one,two,three or more than three.
I don't want to use the template and for each loop.

i tried something as below but i am not getting any value

```
<xsl:if test="(/root/SubRoot/[Section = 'B'])">
 <xsl:value-of select="/root/SubRoot/@type"/>
 </xsl:if>
```

Please suggest me some approach.Any suggesstion and solution must be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't `@type` refer to an attribute ? Have you tried `/root/SubRoot/type` ?

Comment: I am a little bit confused about what your expected result is.

Comment: @Fildor by using /root/SubRoot/type i am getting value for the first SubRoot node.Suppose i want to select type from second node then how i can do that.and number of SubRoot is unknown to me.

Comment: @Zia Is your question not answered?

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks a lot its answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose i want to select type from second node

Use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/SubRoot[2]/type"/>
```

to extract the `type` value from the second `SubRoot` node.

---

Judging from your attempt, you want the `type` value from the `SubRoot` node where `Section` has the value of "B". For this, use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/SubRoot[Section='B']/type"/>
```

Comment: actually number of subroot node is unknown.i dont know how many node is going to come in response and i need to get the value from all the subroot node on the basis of some condition as in my question i have written an if condtion if section iequal to B then get the value of element type from that subroot node.my section value will be unique for each subroot node.

Comment: Well, then the second version should work for you - does it not?

Comment: thank you very much.your second approach is working.i have one question is this type of code have any browser compatibilty issue or it should work with all of the browser.

Comment: @Zia It's pure and simple XSLT 1.0, so I wouldn't expect any problems.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and being my mentor on this issue.keep doing great work